# Why/how does 说 mean update in 下次再说?

Tags: meaning

In the app for 百度网盘 I am prompted to 立即更新 or 下次再说. Clearly [说](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%AA%AA#Chinese) means update, but I don't see any definition that allows that.

Comment: Equivalently: Do you want to update? Yes, immediately/ No, maybe next time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

说 does not mean update, it just means talk or discuss.

下次再说 can be directly translated to **let us talk about that later**.

Answer (score 3):

再说 literal translation is **talk about it again**. For the extention, it means **put off something and decide it later**.

So, 下次再说 means **decide it next time**.